# command to open an existing sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

i know the command to create a database in sqlite. i.e `sqlite3 databasename.sqlite`. But can anybody tell me what is the command to open an existing database in terminal. Please anybody help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply use `sqlite3 myExistingDatabase.sqlite`.

Comment: but i am having a doubt say my existing database name is test. if i write sqlite3 test.sqlite what does it mean am i creating a new database or opening an existing one .Because same is the syntax for creating a new database.

Comment: The behavior is simple and documented (for example in the man-page): if the filename exists it is opened. If it doesn't exist it is created first. If you're still afraid, just make a copy of the original database and try it.